# deployment of qt application on mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, deployment

I am working on a QT gui application that I wish to deploy on mac. After reading through various forums, I have created an app that contains the frameworks and libs, but the application crashes. I have verified that the application works when compiled as a command-line tool. I am giving below the steps and outputs in the hope that someone can help me figure out the problem.

There are three libraries that I am linking to statically, so I assume they cannot be the problem: QGLViewer (http://www.libqglviewer.com/), GLE (http://www.linas.org/gle/), and GLEW.

---

1 - I compile the code as an app-bundle, and check the lib dependencies:

```
otool -L ./AtomTrajectoryViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/AtomTrajectoryViewer 
./AtomTrajectoryViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/AtomTrajectoryViewer:
/Users/bhatia4/macports/Library/Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
/Users/bhatia4/macports/Library/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
/Users/bhatia4/macports/Library/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
/Users/bhatia4/macports/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
/Users/bhatia4/macports/Library/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/Users/bhatia4/macports/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.20.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
/Users/bhatia4/macports/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

2 - I use macdeployqt to deploy the application, and check again the lib dependencies

```
otool -L ./AtomTrajectoryViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/AtomTrajectoryViewer 
./AtomTrajectoryViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/AtomTrajectoryViewer:
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.2)
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.20.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

3 - This all seems to work fine. But when I double-click on the application, it crashes with the following error log.

```
Process:         AtomTrajectoryViewer [12044]
Path:              
/Users/USER/*/AtomTrajectoryViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/AtomTrajectoryViewer
Identifier:      com.yourcompany.AtomTrajectoryViewer
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [432]
Responsible:     AtomTrajectoryViewer [12044]
User ID:         37086

Date/Time:       2015-04-24 14:50:17.069 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F1077)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  3AD366C6-C5BA-EB79-EA67-6D293D1A8B8B

Sleep/Wake UUID: 962187D8-70E2-4886-8371-03303761E575

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8edec866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9a95435c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8e955b1a abort + 125
3   QtCore                          0x0000000100cb5709 0x100c92000 + 145161
4   QtCore                          0x0000000100cb6bb1 QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 161
5   QtGui                           0x0000000100815c08 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() + 5672
6   QtGui                           0x0000000100815c2b QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() + 27
7   QtCore                          0x0000000100e68401 QCoreApplication::init() + 113
8   QtCore                          0x0000000100e68377 QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) + 39
9   QtGui                           0x000000010081338e QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) + 14
10  QtWidgets                       0x000000010022de0e QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 206
11  com.yourcompany.AtomTrajectoryViewer    0x00000001000f28e9 main + 41
12  com.yourcompany.AtomTrajectoryViewer    0x0000000100003854 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8edece6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9a954f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9a957fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8eded662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff990aa421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff990aa136 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8edece6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9a954f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9a957fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff7f5fe310  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbff418  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000707  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff440  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbff418
   r8: 0x0000000103700ac0   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000100f723c8  r13: 0x00000001032006c0  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00007fff5fbffbf0
  rip: 0x00007fff8edec866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000100b402f3

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133
```

Any help if appreciated. Please let me know if more details might be needed on the error. Thanks.

Comment: You might try launching from the command line, the call to `QMessageLogger::fatal` suggest it's writing a message to stderr just before exiting.

Comment: The backtrace suggests that the platform plugin (the filename should be qcocoa.dylib or some such) isn't found.